# Remotely running automated test AutoitX cannot move the mouse or send keys

Tags: java, testing, selenium, testng, autoit

I have a weird specific question.
In my testing framework I have done the following:

1) Using Java and Ant/TestNG to run the tests.

2) Using Selenium to actually run the browser GUI Automation

3) Using AutoitX4Java to able to automate basic mouse movement clicks and send keys

4) Using Windows operating system.

5) Kick off the automated test with an "ant run" command. My build.xml file will compile the java source code and run the test.

So I am actually able to run my automation code successfully. When I am physically in front of my windows machine, and logged in as the local system user. I notice my Java test with AutoitX4Java can move the mouse around and click.

But the problem is when I use another Windows machine and remote connect in using "psexec" or since I have installed ssh on my windows machine, I ssh it runs the Java program and compiles it and runs the test. But it can't move the mouse around. It is almost as if AutoitX4Java just stopped working.

There are time pauses I notice when it runs those lines of code that requires AutoitX4Java. So I know it is doing something. Just appears to not be viewable on the screen (I cannot see mouse movements, right clicks, or send keystrokes) Despite everything else is still viewable (selenium web browser actions.)

I have a monitor that is connected to the physical machine, so I can view what is going on, when I remote in from the other machine.

Here is the Java code I used for the test:

```
package installFFExtension;

import java.lang.*;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

//imports for AutoIT
import autoitx4java.AutoItX;
import com.jacob.com.LibraryLoader;
import java.io.File;

public class firefox extends SeleneseTestBase {
     public Selenium selenium;

@BeforeTest
  public void beforeMethod() {
  selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "firefox", "https://mytestsite.com");
      selenium.start();

  }

@Test
public void extensionInstallation(){

//this part initializes the AutoIT integration into this Selenium Java test
File file = new File("lib", "jacob-1.17-x86.dll"); //path to the jacob dll
    System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());
        AutoItX x = new AutoItX();

    try{
        //dashboard log in
        selenium.windowMaximize();
        selenium.open("/login/");
        selenium.click("id=email");
        selenium.type("id=email", "testuser");
        selenium.type("id=pass", "testpassword");
        selenium.click("id=submitInfo");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");

        selenium.click("link=Install Page");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("Install");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("id=firefox");

        // need to slow selenium to allow page load adding a sleep timer
                Thread.sleep(1000);   
        x.mouseClick("left", 140, 408, 1, 15);
        x.send("installer");
        selenium.type("id=name", "installer");
        x.mouseClick("left", 140, 469, 1, 15);
        x.send("password");
        selenium.type("id=password", "password");
        selenium.click("Install");
        x.mouseClick("left", 222, 372, 1, 15);//this was added to make install bar to go away in Firefox.
        x.mouseClick("left", 150, 523, 1, 15);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
        }
}

@AfterTest
 public void afterMethod() {
    selenium.stop();
  // selenium.shutDownSeleniumServer();
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

AutoIT will only work when the browser is open on the same machine as the test is running.
AutoIT cannot be used when running distributed testing although I have heard claims otherwise using a compiled exe on the remote PC, it sounds complex and unstable.

The question may be is to investigate why you need to use AutoIT at all. What are you trying to achieve which cannot be done via Selenium? What are you trying to test?